# Pointer to two different types of vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Is it possible to create a pointer that either points to a `vector<char>` or a `vector<foo>`? It depends on the data that is handled. If it says it will be chars or need to be foo. foo is a class.

Comment: Possible (`void*`, `union`, …), but not recommended. This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible ? Yes. Good idea ? No !

Comment: yes you can! And why the hell not, but keep the code in a scope else bugs come forward

Comment: Im working on TLVs and its the value that can change, depends on the tag if the value will be a vector of chars or need to be a vector of TLVs.

Comment: @lordkain : because circumventing the type safety leaves you open to all kinds of dangers.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I can't upvote your comment enough...

Comment: @starfable How about something like `vector<shared_ptr<value> >` where `value` is a base class for different types of values?

Comment: C'mon guys, why are you so upset? It is perfectly cool thing to do, OP just doesn't know what's the proper tool for that. See my answer.

Comment: @SergeyA : I agree providing an alternative approach is a perfectly reasonable answer. But the question as it stands (a pointer that points to either ...) is still not a good idea, and for the benefit of the OP and future readers, I think it's worth pointing that out clearly.

Comment: @Biffen Way too complicated and inefficient. Just use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html). It was designed specifically for this.

Comment: @MadameElyse Depends on the rest of the design.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do this safely. For example, you can use `boost::any` or similar tool. It will not be a *pointer*, but I assume, you do not need a single pointer, you need an object which can be one thing or another depending on circumstance.

While I generally dislike the idea of a variable which can by **anything**, I know some people find it useful.

**EDIT**

As correctly noted in comments, judging by the question, `boost::variant` might be better suited - as everywhere when all possible types to be held are known in advance. It is also likely to perform faster.

Comment: Yeah need a object that can be both. Will check it out.

Comment: nebe sure to call the variable objectgender or something :0

Comment: Use `boost::variant`, not `boost::any`. The former gives you more type safety.

Comment: @MadameElyse, they serve different purposes. However, I admit that in the question as stated, boost::variant would be preferred. I will edit the answer.